# JSP Page - Input field type "text" dropping numbers

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page with a basic for with input fields.
I'm noticing that if there is a numeric value within a string then the string cuts off at the number.

For example if my string is 'I am 30' then the field only initialized with 'I am'
If the string says 'I am 30 tomorrow' it still cuts everything off after 30 and shows 'I am'

I have used the debugger to make sure that the entire string is being loaded and sent to the form, and it is. I've never seen this behavior before. Whats happening?

AS far as specs go - this is an older Java 8 app with Spring 4.3.11.RELEASE

INPUT FIELD:

```
 <input type="text"
                   name="serviceClassName"
                   id="serviceClassName"
                   value=${wugService.serviceClassName}
                   required
                   style="width: 25em;"
                   />
```

If I inspect the HTML Code using developer tools, I can see that the value is there but the quotes are ending when the number appears. In the image below the input box should be repopulated with `some 3 some more text test` but you can see where its getting cut off

[image]

I have noticed that if the string contains `-` then the numbers remain. (i.e. `some-3-5-someMore-Words`)

Comment: It should not happen..your code seems okay .Can you put `""` around `${wugService.serviceClassName}` and see onces ?

Comment: Yep - that was it. I change all the value to `"${variableName}`"

Comment: @reactFullStackDeveloper If you solved the problem, please consider answering your own question so other people will not have to scavenge the comments for the answer.